# Ubuntu 14.04 Openssl 1.0.2 Package

Tags: 14.04, apt, openssl

Will the openssl package be upgraded from 1.0.1f to 1.0.2 any time in the future?

(I'm able to build openssl from source as an alternative and am specifically curious about 1.0.2 package availability).

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to know... However, I will say, 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19 was just released on May 3rd.  I am pretty sure they'll keep spot fixing 1.0.1f as needed, unless a major vulnerability requires more serious patching.  FWIW, I'd let ubuntu security team do its thing and keep updating and not compile, unless you have a specific reason for 1.0.2.  I would probably be less efficient at keeping it updated myself.

Comment: Thanks. I had to compile Nginx against OpenSSL 1.0.2 to enable ALPN for HTTP/2.  Google Chrome 51 deprecated NPN support, which prevents HTTP/2 connections from happening with Nginx servers that run OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Comment: "unless you have a specific reason for 1.0.2" - Yep, ALPN for HTTP/2. Let's hope. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS end of life is April 2019. Latest version of OpenSSL supported for it is 1.0.1f. OpenSSL will cease support for 1.0.1 versions on 2016-12-31. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl , https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html

Comment: I came accross this posting for the exact same problem. Is there a solution in sight? We passed the end of 1.0.1 support now but ubuntu 14.04 still only provides 1.0.1. @Chris did you compile 1.0.2 and nginx on your system? I believe this might introduce problems in the future as openssl is used for other parts of the system.

Comment: @merlin: I migrated my services to an Ubuntu 16.04 server instead

Comment: @Chris You made me smile after that much time I spent for the solution of same problem. Cheers! :))

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this for 14.04 is clear:  [No](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1596693).

As the great discussion in the comments suggest, 16.04 is the way forward if you want openssl 1.0.2